# So many "Broken pipe IOE" in ZooKeeper log

Tags: java, sockets, exception, apache-zookeeper

Can any one help to explain why I get so many "Broken pipe IOE" in ZooKeeper log?

ZooKeeper throws this exception almost every minute. I don't think we use the four letter command to dumpWatches so frequently. So what does this mean?

This may be caused by the command `wchc` because our ZooKeeper has more than ten thousand znodes. And I have found that this command is executed from the same server with the different port. Will ZooKeeper call this command frequently?

```
    2014-09-17,10:52:09,179 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: [myid:0] Error sending data synchronously
    java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBufferSync(NIOServerCnxn.java:138)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$SendBufferWriter.checkFlush(NIOServerCnxn.java:453)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$SendBufferWriter.write(NIOServerCnxn.java:474)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:212)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:412)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:429)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:559)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:695)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WatchManager.dumpWatches(WatchManager.java:166)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.dumpWatches(DataTree.java:1240)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$WatchCommand.commandRun(NIOServerCnxn.java:722)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$CommandThread.run(NIOServerCnxn.java:496)
    2014-09-17,10:52:09,179 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: [myid:0] Closed socket connection for client /10.20.201.234:53756 which had sessionid 0x34840357f664081
    2014-09-17,10:52:09,179 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: [myid:0] Error sending data synchronously
    java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBufferSync(NIOServerCnxn.java:138)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$SendBufferWriter.checkFlush(NIOServerCnxn.java:453)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$SendBufferWriter.write(NIOServerCnxn.java:474)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:235)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:276)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.cleanupWriterSocket(NIOServerCnxn.java:424)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.access$000(NIOServerCnxn.java:60)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$CommandThread.run(NIOServerCnxn.java:500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. We're using TaoKeeper to monitor the status of ZooKeeper. It will periodically send `wchc` and other commands to check the status. When ZooKeeper receives `wchc`, the exception occurs because we have too many znodes.

I think TaoKeeper should use `mntr` rather than `wchc` which may affect ZooKeeper's performance when it has large number of znodes.